Unable to save complex datatypes in Postgres
I need a empty migration when i migrate newly. I dont want the password history to repeat
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The history of the changed password
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> PasswordHistory { get; set; } = [];
}


The password history field has a default value as array here i provide the identity configuration below
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
  {
      var adminUser = new User
      {
          Id = AdminUserId,
          UserName = "admin@xxx.com",
          EmailConfirmed = true,
          SecurityStamp = "",
          ConcurrencyStamp = "",
          LockoutEnabled = true,
          FirstName = "Admin",
          LastName = "",
          IdpUser = false,
          Enabled = true,
      };


This the migration code
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;


namespace Db.Postgres.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class AddPasswordHistoryToUser : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<List<string>>(
                name: "PasswordHistory",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                type: "text[]",
                nullable: false);

            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                keyColumn: "Id",
                keyValue: "C52E290D-4971-4284-923D-D9E8EE2F04CC",
                column: "PasswordHistory",
                value: new List<string>());
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "PasswordHistory",
                table: "AspNetUsers");
        }
    }
}

this was the actuall migration but I changed like below i metioned
public partial class AddPasswordHistoryToUser : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<List<string>>(
                name: "PasswordHistory",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                type: "text[]",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: new List<string>());
        }

But now the password histor field is repeating for each and every migration
migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
       table: "AspNetUsers",
       keyColumn: "Id",
       keyValue: "C52E290D-4971-4284-923D-D9E8EE2F04CC",
       column: "PasswordHistory",
       value: new List<string>());

the db cant recognize this change how to solve this i dont wqant to repeat this field in each and every migration.

What postgres version do you use? This was introduced in a recent version.

I am using 8.6 version

It seems like 8.6 is a pgAdmin version not a postgres version. Because postgres 8.4 is from 2009

EF Core doesn’t automatically know how to save a List in the database. By default, it tries to use a database array type (text[] in PostgreSQL). However, this doesn’t match well with EF Core’s internal handling, especially when combined with default values.
    builder.Entity<User>()
.Property(u => u.PasswordHistory)
.HasConversion(
    v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions?)null),
    v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions?)null) ?? new List<string>()
);

